# PySimpleGUI in python: Disable window move by user(with CTRL+mouse1)

Tags: python, pysimplegui, window-position

A window can be moved by holding down CTRL and Mouse1, I would love to deactivate it, or deactivate window moving in general.

My problem is, that I use the CTRL key to mark multiple images in my explorer.
After my image is marked, the image is processed in PIL, which takes like 100-200ms.
So when the user holds down CTRL and clicks mouse1, the image gets processed in PIL. The user releases mouse1 and moves to the next element, the whole window is moved a fair amount(~100 pixels], where the user is moving the mouse to.(I guess the mouse1 click is still in buffer, and gets not updated to "is_released", while the program is busy)

My code is way to split(multiple files) up and too long to post, but I think my question is pretty straightforward and simple enough. toggle/block/unblock move window ability. Favorably deactivating CTRL-move in general, so the user can still use the titlebar.
I searched the docs, and found window.move(), but putting the window back to the original position would not be a pretty solution...lol

Thank you.

Comment: Thought about not using CTRL for your tasks if it conflicts?

Comment: avoiding problems is not a solution. CTRL for multielement selection is standard in windows and other programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [PySimpleGUI Call Reference](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/)

Option in `Window`

> grab_anywhere_using_control
>
> If True can use CONTROL key + left mouse mouse to click and drag to move the window. DEFAULT is TRUE. Unlike normal grab anywhere, it works on all elements.

```py
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, grab_anywhere_using_control=False)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH.
I fixed it 9 out of 10 times with
`
import win32api, win32con;
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
`
before I call the imageupdate function to FORCE mouse1_is released, but yours will be perfect.
OMG just wanted to ask where I can find this stuff myself, and until now I thought
https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/ is the DOCUMENTQATION
but there is more:
https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/
lol..I was wondering why I can't seem to find stuff.
Less stupid questions from me in the future
https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/